# Magento 2.2 - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::load()

Tags: magento2.2, model, sales, database-connection

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::load() in
>   /var/www/html/magento2_dev/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:536

Just adding the resource connection on my extended Sales Model, getting the above issue.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
namespace Sdi\Sales\Model;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
class Order extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
{
   protected $_resource;
   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
) {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
}
public function bnDelete()
{
    if ($this->getStatus() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED) {
        $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $query = 'SQL QUERY';
        $connection->query($query);
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to do sql queries from within class. Need to do something like this

```php
public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
)
{
    $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $this->resource = $resource;
}

public function sampleMethod()
{
    $tableName = $this->resource->getTableName('table');
    $select =  $this->connection
       ->select()
        ->from(['o' => $tableName])
        ->where('o.value=?', '2')
        ->group('o.value')
       ->order('o.value', 'ASC');
    echo (string) $select;
    return $select;
}
```